# Getting warning error in vhdl code

Tags: warnings, vhdl

I keep getting a strange error in my code, it compiles fine but I keep getting a warning:

Warning: Unconnected, internal signal \s(0)D\ is promoted to input PIN.

Warning: Unconnected, internal signal \s(1)D\ is promoted to input PIN.

The code is for a basic register which resets, shifts to the left and inserts S_IN, and loads the values set into the register using Pload. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with it?

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity special_register is
port( DATA:                 in    std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);     
    Reset:                  in    std_logic;
    PLoad:                  in    std_logic;
    S_Right:                in    std_logic;
    S_IN:                   in    std_logic;
    clock :                 in    std_logic;
    S:                      in    std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    D:                      out   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Q :                     out   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end special_register;

architecture behav of special_register is
begin
process(clock, data, Reset, S_IN, S, S_Right, PLoad)
begin
if rising_edge(clock) then
S(0) <= (S_Right);
S(1) <= (PLoad);
if (S(1) = '1') then
    D(3) <= DATA(3);
    D(2) <= DATA(2);
    D(1) <= DATA(1);
    D(0) <= DATA(0);
else if (S(0) = '0') then
    D(0) <= Q(1);
    D(1) <= Q(2);
    D(2) <= Q(3);
    D(3) <= S_IN;       
end if;
end if;
end if;
end process;
Q(3) <= (NOT Reset) AND D(3);
Q(2) <= (NOT Reset) AND D(2);
Q(1) <= (NOT Reset) AND D(1);
Q(0) <= (NOT Reset) AND D(0);
end behav;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Brian's answer you could note that this design specification is not VHDL compliant and the presumed synthesis tool isn't either:

`ghdl -a special_register.vhdl
special_register.vhdl:21:2: port "s" can't be assigned
special_register.vhdl:22:2: port "s" can't be assigned
special_register.vhdl:29:14: port "q" cannot be read
special_register.vhdl:30:14: port "q" cannot be read
special_register.vhdl:31:14: port "q" cannot be read
special_register.vhdl:37:26: port "d" cannot be read
special_register.vhdl:38:26: port "d" cannot be read
special_register.vhdl:39:26: port "d" cannot be read
special_register.vhdl:40:26: port "d" cannot be read
ghdl: compilation error`

(It would seem you are trying to read an output port as well).